# Responsive annotation in ggplot - annotate graph with shapes and text that changes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the graph below in ggplot.

[image: Graph]

I am running into two issues

1. How do you annotate a graph with some object (say, the bracket sign "{") and have it scale or otherwise be responsive to a specified amount?
2. How do you add a border around an individual fill line? I want "deficit" to be white with a dashed black border.

Here is how the data is structured:

```
> gap_analysis_plot_data
     income_range    control total            variable value
1   0% to 30% MFI Households 29590 matched_units_to_hh  7525
2   0% to 30% MFI      Units 10665 matched_units_to_hh  7525
3  31% to 50% MFI Households 19430 matched_units_to_hh  3255
4  31% to 50% MFI      Units 15440 matched_units_to_hh  3255
5   0% to 30% MFI Households 29590     paying_too_much 22065
6   0% to 30% MFI      Units 10665     paying_too_much  3095
7  31% to 50% MFI Households 19430     paying_too_much 14980
8  31% to 50% MFI      Units 15440     paying_too_much  5910
9   0% to 30% MFI Households 29590        vacant_units     0
10  0% to 30% MFI      Units 10665        vacant_units    45
11 31% to 50% MFI Households 19430        vacant_units     0
12 31% to 50% MFI      Units 15440        vacant_units   690
13  0% to 30% MFI Households 29590      getting_a_deal     0
14  0% to 30% MFI      Units 10665      getting_a_deal     0
15 31% to 50% MFI Households 19430      getting_a_deal  1195
16 31% to 50% MFI      Units 15440      getting_a_deal  5585
17  0% to 30% MFI Households 29590        existing_gap     0
18  0% to 30% MFI      Units 10665        existing_gap 18925
19 31% to 50% MFI Households 19430        existing_gap     0
20 31% to 50% MFI      Units 15440        existing_gap  3990
```

And here is the code I have so far to generate the graph below.

```
p <- gap_analysis_plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x = control, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~income_range) + 
    labs(title = 'Affordability gap', subtitle = gtitle, x = "", y = "Number of households or units\n") +
    scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = group.colors,
                  name = "",
                  breaks = c('existing_gap', 'getting_a_deal', 'vacant_units', 'paying_too_much', 'matched_units_to_hh'),
                  labels = c('Existing gap', 'Renting down\n(getting a deal)', 'Vacant units', 'Renting up\n(paying too much)', 'Matched units')
)
> print(p)
```

[image: Gap analysis from ggplot]

I'm also curious if you have tips on how to add direct labels if it's not overly complicated. Notice the slight variation in the label names however.

Comment: Your code produces a plot with two facets. Are you looking for a separate bracket on each facet?

Comment: @Z.Lin The facet isn't as important to me right now. Separate brackets on each facet would be nice, but I am more looking for at least one functional (responsive) bracket.